# Find match in file and remove line and the line under

Tags: php

I am trying to edit a text file using PHP.
My source file is called source.txt

There are multiple lines such as

```
    NAME_OF_TITLE,Flowers
    http://get.php?key=1223

    NAME_OF_TITLE,Toys (unavailable)
    http://get.php?key=1923

    NAME_OF_TITLE,Cards
    http://get.php?key=1023

    NAME_OF_TITLE,Food (unavailable)
    http://get.php?key=1123

    ......
```

As you can see, there are lines where is comment

```
    (unavailable)
```

I know, how to remove the line where is this phrase (unavailable) but I need to remove as well the line under. My desired result would be this.

```
    NAME_OF_TITLE,Flowers
    http://get.php?key=1223

    NAME_OF_TITLE,Cards
    http://get.php?key=1023
```

ORIGINAL CODE

```
    $file = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/test/source.txt");
    $lines = explode("\n", $file);
    $exclude = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strpos($line, 'unavailable') !== FALSE) {
    continue;
    }
    $exclude[] = $line;
    }
    echo    implode("\n", $exclude);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The recommended procedure is to start by writing some code: Read the lines of the file into an array, find lines that match, edit the array to remove the corresponding line and the next one, repeat. When you get stuck, come back and ask a question about that specific problem.

Comment: ie : show the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
 $lines = file('text.txt');
 foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
     if (strpos($line, '(unavailable)')) {
         unset($lines[$line_num]);
         unset($lines[$line_num+1]);
     }
 }
 $fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w+');
 foreach ($lines as $line_num=>$line) {
     fwrite($fp, $line);
 }
 fclose($fp);
?>
```

file text.txt content:

```
NAME_OF_TITLE,Flowers
http://get.php?key=1223

NAME_OF_TITLE,Toys (unavailable)
http://get.php?key=1923

NAME_OF_TITLE,Cards
http://get.php?key=1023

NAME_OF_TITLE,Food (unavailable)
http://get.php?key=1123
```

File file.txt content:

```
NAME_OF_TITLE,Flowers
http://get.php?key=1223


NAME_OF_TITLE,Cards
http://get.php?key=1023
```